# Variables preserved and used only in true state

Tags: c#, winforms

I now got this problem to solve. With winform I made a video player (WMP lib) with a playlist (`treeview`). And I implemented the function which allows me to resize the playlist during running. My next target is to enable the "Hide/Show" function of the playlist. My idea is having a `checkbox` (`checkbox1`), when checked the playlist shows and when unchecked it hides. Here "hide" means the playlist's width becomes 0 and the screen  becomes as wide as the form. The playlist we usually use is like when the playlist shows again from hiding, it occupies the same space as it was before hiding, as well as the screen. I just want this function, but I've no idea how to implement it.

```
  private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       if (this.checkBox1.Checked == true)
       {
           // to be implemented
       }
       else
       {
            treeView1.Width = 0;
            axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Width = this.Width;     
       }
  }
```

The code to be completed is the one like above. My idea is like having a variable recording the width of the playlist (`treeview1.Width`), since when it's showing, the user would frequently resize it. When it shows again from hiding state, this variable could be used again to be assigned to the `treeview1.Width`. However I'm not quite clear how to do that. Anybody got an idea? thanks.

Comment: Idea? Start reading documentation - I am sure the media player has an event that is triggered on size / position change and you can use to record the real size.

Comment: This is a classic X-Y problem.  Setting the width of a control to zero is a ridiculous way to "hide" something.  Don't do this.  Controls *all* have a `Visible` property that controls their visibility.  I suggest you use it.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @J... well....thanks for reminding me that, and it works! I tried the visible thing before but I forgot to set the width of the screen to the width of the form.....that's a stupid negligence. Thank you again for the solution anyway, and I'm wondering if there's way to sign your comment as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide any control then use `Visible` property of that control.
for example:

```
textbox1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Yes thanks, as I commented above. That's the solution!